# connect to self hosted webservice running in Android app in emulator

Tags: android, web-services

I implemented a web-service in Android app listening to a port.
I have another console desktop app which connects to it.

This works fine when running the Android app on device.
On emulator, it's a problem because it's basically same connection with computer.

How can I connect to the web-service running in the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use Genymotion as emulator (https://www.genymotion.com/).
It's more performant than original emulator and use virtual machine mecanism.
Therefore, your emulator will have his dedicated (but virtual) network interface. Allowing it to have its own IP address.

This will make sockets listening available on your local network.

Comment: thanks for your comment, didn't know Genymotion has this feature. However, I'm looking to do this with the Android emulator since Genymotion is not free

Comment: Genymotion has a free version that may, depending of what you need, be enough. (Free as free beer)

Comment: yes, but the free version does not enable some features https://www.genymotion.com/#!/store

Comment: actually this isn't about Genymotion I'm really looking to use Android emulator because I'm automating some stuff

Comment: Android's emulator seems to have redirection  http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection but I'm not sure if / how it helps me